# Apply Scrolling effect using CSS and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm looking for a special scrolling effect used for example on this page:
http://www.lemonde.fr/ameriques/visuel/2014/10/10/voix-d-outretombe-les-derniers-mots-de-condamnes-a-mort-executes-au-texas_4501418_3222.html
When you scroll, the page doesn't follow your scroll, but follow an animation. I don't know how to do it. I tried to use jquery and the scroll event, it's working on chrome but not on safari, and is definitely less smooth than on the example. 
I guess i have to take into account the scroll "speed" but don't know how to do something that smooth.

Any idea how to do it ? (i'd rather have an explanation than a plugin, but every answer is most welcome).
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This concept is similar to any jquery slider (but little different)

1. Split your site into seperate pages (seperate divs) with 100% and height 100% (basically one `div` has to cover the viewing window);
2. Use `CSS` to hide the scroller;
   Use the below code

   ```
   body{
       overflow:hidden;
   }
   ```
3. Then bind a function to window scroll event

   ```
   $(window).scroll(function(){

   })
   ```
4. Detect the scroll. if scroll is `down` then animate to next page else if scroll is `up` then animate too previous page.
   Use the below code to test scroll up and down

   ```
   var lastScrollTop = 0;
   $(window).scroll(function(event){
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (st > lastScrollTop){
           // downscroll code
       } else {
           // upscroll code
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;
   });
   ```

   Use the below script to animate to pages

   ```
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('div id').offset().top})
   ```

   So it ill be something similar to

   ```
   var lastScrollTop = 0;
   $(window).scroll(function(event){
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (st > lastScrollTop){
           $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('next div id').offset().top})
       } else {
           $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('prev div id').offset().top})
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I use the same thing but i want the user to scroll more before launching the animation. For that, i use a counter (50 for instance), and at every scroll event i do 50--. When the counter==0 i launch the animation. The issue is that it's good on chrome and firefox, but very ugly on safari...

Comment: not sure what you mean by `very ugly`. you mean low frame rate?

Comment: Well before counter==50, i force the browser not to scroll ( with scrollTop(0) ), but safari seems to scroll a bit first and then go back to 0, at every scroll event. Not good for the eyes